# Using MAPI to retrieve the list of emails from GAL

Tags: python, mapi, gal

This is my code so far:

```
import win32com.client

o = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
ns = o.GetNamespace("MAPI")

adrLi = ns.AddressLists.Item("Global Address List")
contacts = adrLi.AddressEntries
numEntries = adrLi.AddressEntries.Count

nameAliasDict = {}

for i in contacts:
    name = i.Name
    alias = i.Address.split("=")[-1]
    print i.GetExchangeUser().PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A56101E")
```

I"m getting the property from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446002.aspx

But for some reasons, I get this error:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, u'Microsoft Outlook', u'The property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A550003" is unknown or cannot be found.', None, 0, -2147221233), None)
```

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assume that `PR_CONTACT_EMAIL_ADDRESSES` or any other MAPI property will be available. Your code must expect and handle that error from `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`.
Check if you can actually see the property on that particular object in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click IAddrBook, "Open Root Container" etc.).

Why exactly do you need that property? If you just need the SMTP address. use `ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress`.